# ag-grid(facing issue with this.gridOptions.api.exportDataAsExcel)

Tags: angular, typescript, callback, logic, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid with angular.This is my code to export file to excel :

```
this.gridOptions.api.exportDataAsExcel({
  fileName: `test`,
  sheetName: 'test Information By Date',
  processCellCallback: this.processCellCallback,
} as ExcelExportParams);
```

and my call back function is

```
processCellCallback(params:ExportParams): any {
  const colId = params.column.getColId();
  return params.value;
}
```

My issue is I need to show an alert when the exportation is done, but I did not find a single method which does that. I want to check when the export is done or completed and then show my popup.

Please help me, if anybody has a genuine solution. I tried many tricks, for example: I have the total records so I tried to check every row where I can compare every row with total records but `processCellCallback` doesn't use any global or local variables declarations.
I am using this as common code for all of components.

Comment: one simple solution would be to wrap `this.gridOptions.api.exportDataAsExcel` inside a function and `alert()` after this method. since the method is synchronous your alert will pop up as soon as excel is in process of downloading file to download location.

Comment: I already tried that too but it did not work and It won't work if you have records like 10 thousands or more than that.